# First Character Indented in Textbox

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that includes a textbox, styled with id = #txtarea.  It is in another div with id = #newtext

```
<div id="newtext">
<p>Enter Your Text Into the Box</p>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id = "txtArea"  > </textarea>
</div>
```

The relevant css is:

```
#newtext {margin-top:300px;text-align:center;font-size:60px;padding:10px;margin- 
left:20px;margin-right:20px}
#txtArea {font-size:30px}
```

The code works well except that when I enter text into the text box, the first word is indented one space.  Is there a way to get around that?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this space in the markup.. whatever is between the `textarea` element tags is rendered as text, thus the whitespace was evaluated as spacing text.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtArea"> </textarea>
                                          ^
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/3m8Em/)

Comment: while I see it works in your example, for some reason it is not working on my computer.  Tested it in Firefox and Safari, both are indenting still after I copied and pasted your code.  Any ideas - could there be something elsewhere in my code that could effect this?

Comment: Ok, it does work, I still had the space there.  It's gone now and all is good.  Thanks a lot.